# Confidence intervals for proportions (prevalence)

Tags: confidence-interval

I have some data on a sample of $n=1776$ hospitals. For each hospital there is a total number of patients (`patients`), and a number of patients diagnosed with a particular condition (`diagnosed`). Do I take the mean of this proportion,`diagnosed`/`patients`, for all hospitals in the sample, $\hat{\mu}$, and calculate a 95% confidence interval as $\hat{\mu} \pm 1.96\sigma / \sqrt{n}$ or as $\hat{\mu} \pm 1.96  \sqrt{\hat{\mu}(1-\hat{\mu})/n}$ ? Or.... ?

**Update**

[Following comments from whuber]. Additionally, the data are broken down into 2 age groups (young and old) and 3 risk scores. That is, all 1776 hospitals have total numbers of patients as follows:

```
               younger patients       older patients             

Low risk            A                      D

Medium risk         B                      E

High risk           C                      F
```

...and similarly for the numbers of patients with the condition.

So, for each combination of age group and risk score, I would like to estimate the mean prevalence and a confidence interval for it.

Here is some summary of the data

```
Risk   age    mean   sd      n
1      u50    0.37   0.19    1776
2      u50    0.49   0.25    1776
3      u50    0.54   0.26    1776
1      o50    0.45   0.36    1776
2      o50    0.52   0.42    1776
3      o50    0.67   0.41    1776
```

Comment: Consider providing some simple summary stats of your data, because you ought to get different kinds of replies depending on how large these fractions and numbers of patients tend to be.

Comment: @whuber I have added some stats. Is this what you had in mind ? I am sorry if I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: Yes, Joe, that's right. Your other comment to a reply is also telling: the presence of some small and even zero ratios *for individual hospitals* is important to know.  Your entry for risk=2, age=o50 is interesting, because the large SD of 0.42 compared to the mean of 0.52 is consistent *only* with data where about half of the hospitals are at or near zero and the other half are at or near 100%!  (This presumes the ratios cannot exceed 100% individually: there are no multiple diagnoses for the same patient.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try a nonparametric bootstrap approach. For example

```
require(boot)
the.means = function(dt, i) {mean(dt[i])}
boot.obj <- boot(data=mydata, statistic=the.means , R=10000) 
quantile(boot.obj$t, c(.025,.975))
```

You can repeat this for each of your 6 subsets of data.

Comment: Thank you ! I don't know that much about bootstrapping, but the result of running this code on my data seems very encouraging !

Answer (score 6):

Joe,

Check to see if (sample size)*(proportion diagnosed) >= 5 for each hospital or group of hospitals by age/risk score. If so, then the normal dbn closely approximates the binomial dbn and the 95% CI = p_hat +/- 1.96*(p_hat*(1-p_hat)/n)^0.5 formula may be used.

For a better approximation, use the Wilson score interval (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval).

Robert

Comment: Thank you ! (sample size)*(proportion diagnosed) is less than 5 for some hospitals, but there are relatively few of these....

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Regression Approach**

Here's a way that might work. You can "expand" your data to patient level, so each row corresponds to a patient, who is either diagnosed or not. It might look like this:

> hospital   age   risk   diagnosed
>              1     1      0   1
>              1     0      1   0
>              1     1      2   1

Then you estimate a binary model, such as a probit, where your dependent variables are dummies for the risk-age group interactions. You may also want to cluster on the hospital. Then you can calculate the predictive margins for each risk-age dummy.

**This will not work**

You can hack this in a regression context by simple linear model of $\log(y)$ on a constant, and exponentiating the coefficients and CIs. This will give you geometric mean and its CI, which is appropriate mean to use since you are dealing with rates. Since all your $\mu$s are greater than zero, taking logs won't cost you any data.

Here's an example in Stata:

```
. sysuse auto,clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. generate logprice=log(price)

. regress logprice, eform(GM)

      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =      74
-------------+------------------------------           F(  0,    73) =    0.00
       Model |           0     0           .           Prob > F      =       .
    Residual |  11.2235331    73  .153747029           R-squared     =  0.0000
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.0000
       Total |  11.2235331    73  .153747029           Root MSE      =  .39211

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    logprice |         GM   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   5656.907   257.8496   189.56   0.000     5165.664    6194.866
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. means price

    Variable |    Type        Obs        Mean       [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------
       price | Arithmetic      74    6165.257        5481.914     6848.6 
             |  Geometric      74    5656.907        5165.664   6194.865 
             |   Harmonic      74    5296.672        4928.901    5723.75 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note that the geometric mean matches the regression output very nicely. I learned about this from Roger Newson's [Stata Tip #1](http://www.imperial.ac.uk/nhli/r.newson/papers/gmratio.pdf).

Comment: Because it's possible that some observed rates *will* be zero, and those are useful data, it seems that taking logarithms cannot quite be the right thing to do.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I don't understand ! But thanks anyway !

Comment: @whuber I vividly recall that the all the $\mu$s were between 0.3 and 0.8, but that seems to have disappeared in the edit (or I made it up). You are certainly correct that this will not work if that's not the case.

Comment: @Joe King What sort of statistics software do you have access to?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov if you are suggesting that I take the log of the individual hospital rates and regress these on (I'm not sure what) then indeed some of them are zero for the individual hospitals. The 0.3-0.8 I mentioned was a rough indication of the the means of the rates - the actual range is 0.37 to 0.67 (as you can see from the table that I added in my last edit). Hope I am making sense ?

Comment: Dimitriy, In the original the means were said to range from $0.3$ to $0.8$ and SDs from $0.2$ to $0.4$. Those statistics indicate the data probably have some zero values. For almost *any* condition, I would expect at least a few hospitals out of two thousand or so not to observe it for some stretch of time, so fractions of $0$ really need to be handled.

Comment: @Joe King. Create a variable that is the natural log of the ratio of diagnosed to patients for each hospital in each group (like youngsters with low risk). For each group separately (so $N=1,776$), regress this number on a constant. This gives you an estimate of the constant $\hat \alpha$ and confidence interval for it (usually a 95% one) that looks like [a,b]. If you  calculate $e^{\hat \alpha}$, $e^{a}$, and $e^{b}$, you will have the geometric mean of the prevalence and its CI for each group. Do that for each group, and you have your 9 means.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you were saying. I thought each hospital had a strictly positive number of diagnosed patients. Since that is not the case, my approach won't work.

Comment: The new approach ought to work, but won't it estimate the mean *personal* diagnosis rate rather than the mean *hospital* diagnosis rate?

Comment: @whuber You're right again. I don't know where my head is today.

Comment: @whuber, am I able to use one of the methods I wrote about in my post to estimate the hospital rate CI ?

Comment: Joe: Sure--but it won't be as accurate as you might like :-). Conceptually, the issue is that the data for hospitals with smaller numbers of patients will be less precise than data for the larger hospitals, so some form of weighting ought to be employed.

Comment: @whuber thank you again - is one method more applicable than the other ? Also, regarding weighting, could you provide more info (or a reference ?)

Comment: Raw weighting doesn't work well. (For reference, see any elementary stats textbook, because they all discuss the variance of binomial variables, and refer to any account of OLS regression to learn how variances can be used in weighted regression.) Because these are binomial data, think about using a generalized linear model with binomial response.  Given the ranges of diagnosis rates you are seeing, the logit link is advisable (rather than log or linear).

Comment: @whuber, thanks again, so the individual hospital rates will be the response variable, but what should the explanatory variable(s) be ?

Comment: @whuber, I am going around in circles trying to find out how to do this. Maybe I am searching for the wrong thing ? I don't have any textbook, so I am using google to search for "confidence interval for a proportion"+"binomial regression" - so far I have not found anything yet......

Comment: @whuber after some experimentation I found I can use Rs glm() function with family=binomial(link=logit) with the individual hospital rates as response and no covariates, with `weights=` set to the variable which is the denominator in the hospital rates, and take the inverse logit of the estimate for the intercept, I get the same estimate for mean rate as just taking the mean of all the rates. I think this makes sense. But how do I get a confidence interval from there ? Do I take the inverse logit of the reported standard error ? That seems to be very large...